# What's the best way to share real-time GPS coordinates among a group?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mobile, gps

I'm designing a game that requires the players to know the GPS real-world location of the other players in (close to) real-time.  There could be ~ 5 seconds of delay and still function well.

The target platform is Android, however I was interested in including my iPhone friends, so I was hoping to build this on the web using HTML5, Javascript and PHP.

I've tried a few different approaches such as BeaconPush and constantly reading/writing to a MySQL database, but I am not sure the BEST and most efficient way to go about it.  I start writing a bunch of code and then discover a problem and try another route and seem to keep bumping my head.

The game is a little bit like Pac-Man.  Three players are trying to "catch" one player.  The one player has a specific objective on a real-world map.  The game grabs coordinates from a database and spawns objects/icons on to a Google map. Using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition the game checks for hit detection with the items and the players can pickup items as they pass over them.  All of this works fine, but the map has to be able to update object icons as they get removed and update icons with the locations of the other players in near-real time.  I'm not sure how to share everyone's GPS location in the most efficient way.  The whole game is basically functioning and working, except this one (albeit giant) piece of the puzzle.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Considering most GPS devices are not very precise (~ 20m), you'd need a pretty big place to play this, huh?

Comment: Even with WiFi I wouldn't expect sync from device to DB to other device in 5 seconds. Sounds like overexpectations to me. Good luck.

Comment: @NullUserException Yes, it's a city-wide game; collision detection is currently set to a quarter of a mile.  @M'vy That's what I am fearful of...I'm hoping to find the best compromise considering the technology and see if it will work.

Comment: Don't tell me you'll need a car to play this. About the technology, what you use on the server side will hardly be a factor. Try it out with MySQL/PHP and see how it works. If it's too slow I would invest more on a server with better bandwidth/latency (or better phones/carriers).

Comment: Yes, the idea is to have a driver and a passenger/operator for each car (pairs of 2) with the phones powered by the car and displays set to never turn off so that GPS data is always being sent.  There's speed limits capped on the game using coords.speed.  The game is strategy based (settings traps, using back roads) so safety isn't an issue as reckless driving buys you nothing.  I'm more worried about gas prices and sharing GPS data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so your question is how to effectively communicate between a SERVER, and multiple CLIENTS in near real-time.  You have two problems, effective communication with the client. And effective communication between 'sessions' on the server.

#### HTTP CLIENT TO SERVER

The http protocol is not stateful. Meaning you send a request the server responds, and then the connection is closed. This makes it hard to communicate in a bi-directional or event-driven manner like a game demands. This is why most networked games use UDP which has much less overhead to sending information.
We have to use TCP/IP and we have to use the HTTP protocol in this scenario so how can we do it efficiently?

Comet is the answer.  A Comet Server is just a 'term' that means a server that keeps a connection open for a long time to continually send data to a client.  Comet servers use asynchronous streaming (ajax) connections that allow the client to 'know' when new information has arrived without having to read the whole response.
See also: Long Polling
[PHP Comet Server](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start)

#### SESSION TO SESSION

When the server receives a request it needs to ask the question "Where is everyone else" and it needs to ask this question often and efficiently.
Mysql is not going to be the best technology solution for something like this.  You want to write and read small values VERY VERY quickly from multiple processes (each http client)

Why send the data across a network connection, decode it to from a string (sql) and then wait for the server to decode insert or respond, etc - that all sounds like a lot of extra overhead.

What you need is true IPC (inter process communication).  This is hard to achieve in PHP but it can be done.  Using shared memory, or even writing to a memory mapped file would be the best solution for the highest rate of reading and writing GPS coordinate updates.
[PHP IPC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php)

#### Tying it together:

A client sends a request to the server and starts polling it.  The server reads the shared memory to see what the coordinates of others are.  The server writes a line to the open connection that contains a JSON string describing the locations of all the players.
At the same time while the client is polling the server it must also send a request to the server describing its location, and the server must write this value to shared memory.
The program stays in a continuous loop until the client closes the http connection.

See These:

- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-loreto-http-bidirectional-00
- http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html

If shared memory is not an option then I would suggest using a different database or something simpler such as a key-value store (memcache) or even mongodb.  They both will have less transactional overhead, and be able to insert and poll much more quickly than MySQL

A third option is using PostgreSQL as the IPC mechanism. You can use LISTEN events for this - but that's getting a bit contrived.

#### Notes:

This solution will not scale very well with PHP.  Lets say you're using apache and you have 20 workers in your worker pool.  When you reach 20 connections all of the servers php processes will be consumed by other requests, so the 21st request will endlessly wait for a worker to become available.

The best solution is to implement the Comet server / long-polling in something like Twisted, or any other asynchronous framework.